# Finding collision between two rotated SVG text elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, rotation

I am working with SVG elements. I wish to rotate a SVG text element and also have to find whether it is colliding with nearby text elements.

[image]

In this I have achieved rotation. But facing concern on finding collision. To find collision, I am obtaining values using getBoundingClientRect() for text elements after rotation and comparing those.

The issue I am facing is, the labels are returned as collided even when a text enter inside the rect box of previous text element. But you can see those are not collided.

I need to found whether text is collided with previous text element exactly.

Help to resolve this..
Thanks !

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jquerycollision/

Comment: http://raphaeljs.com/ should be perfect for this.